# how to install cordova OCR?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ocr

I'm trying to convert image to text. 
I used this code:

```
function convertText() {
    var imagePath2="https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/iOS/ios11-iphone7-settings-cellular.jpg";
        Tesseract.recognise(imagePath2,successCallback2,errorCallback2);
    }

    function successCallback2 (result) {
        alert(result);
    }

    function errorCallback2 (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
```

But the result is (Class not found) 
What can I do ?

Comment: try to `clean project` or `rebuild project`

Comment: until now the same problem